# Option index of the acro package not working

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, acro

I am trying to use the `index` option of the `acro` package to auto-include acronyms in the index (created by the package `imakeidx`). This, however, doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong or is this a problem of the `acro` package?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[index]{acro}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\DeclareAcronym{blah}{short=blah, long=a random acronym}
\DeclareAcronym{blahblah}{short=blahblah, long=another random acronym}

\begin{document}

This is the demonstration of the usage of \ac{blah}---which is not to be confused with \ac{blahblah}.

\printacronyms

\printindex

\end{document}
```

---

**Edit:**

A working MWE in `acro` version 3 would be the following:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\acsetup{
    index/use=true
}

\DeclareAcronym{blah}{short=blah, long=a random acronym}
\DeclareAcronym{blahblah}{short=blahblah, long=another random acronym}

\begin{document}

This is the demonstration of the usage of \ac{blah}---which is not to be confused with \ac{blahblah}.

\printacronyms

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a bug in the `acro` package – more precisely in the definition of `\acro_reset_specials:`. I'll fix it and will update to CTAN.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I opened an issue on your bitbucket-repository right before your response which is obsolete then :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is basically a bug report.

Comment: @cgnieder Hihi ! Is it just me or the index option of the acro package is still bugging ?
I use the exact same code as in the question and no index appears.

Comment: @JeT I think the syntax has changed in acro version 3 (see section 16.2 of the [manual](https://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/macros/latex/contrib/acro/acro-manual.pdf)).  
Adding `\acsetup{index/use=true}` and removing the `index` option from `usepackage` should make the example work :)

Comment: @JeT I added a complete MWE to the original question, maybe you can try it out :)

Comment: @JKR merci ! It works now. Much appreciated.

Comment: @JeT Great! You're welcome :)